react native release build issue | index.android.bundle file not created in assets folder after upgrade target sdk to 34 and gradle version to 7.4.2
gradle file
..........
buildscript {
apply from: "../node_modules/@dynatrace/react-native-plugin/files/plugin.gradle", to: buildscript
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "34.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 29
        compileSdkVersion = 34
        targetSdkVersion = 34
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15')
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}
......

and gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists

When I am running my app in debug mode it's working fine but after creating release build index.android.bundle file is not created within the assets folder. Due to that .apk file is not running successfully on the device.
Note I got the solution here:
https://github.com/react-native-community/upgrade-support/issues/38
according to above solution I need to run this npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle command to generate bundle file manually.
My concern is why it's not created automatically like previously it was created with the Gradle version 7.0.4.
Please help with the root cause of this issue.

What do you mean by " .apk file is not running successfully on the device. " its crashing on start or your app functionality is broken ?

I had same issue after upgrade target sdk to 34 and gradle version to 7.4.2 and finally I could able to generate index.android.bundle file manually by running this command
npx react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res

and it will generate index.android.bundle in android/app/src/main/assets folder.
